# CUDA atomicAdd failed

Tags: c++, image, cuda, atomic, itk

The following CUDA kernel is supposed to do image slices addition for an 3D image, i.e., you collapse the 3D volume along one dimension and produce one 2D image through doing pixel-wise additions. The image_in data pointer has size 128 * 128 * 128, which was obtained from an ITK::Image using the function GetOutputBuffer(). After reading the ITK documentation, I think we can safely assume that the data pointer points to an segment of continuous memory of the image data, without padding. The image_out is just a 2D image of size 128 * 128, also produced from  an ITK::Image. I included the info about the images just for completeness but the question is more about CUDA atomic and might be very elementary. The code compute the thread id first and project the id into the range of 128 * 128, which means all pixels in the same line along the dimension we perform addition will have the same idx. Then using this idx, atomicAdd was used to update the image_out.

```
__global__ void add_slices(int* image_in, int* image_out) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int idx = tid % (128 * 128);
    int temp = image_in[tid];

    atomicAdd( &image_out[idx], temp );

}
```

The way I initialized the image_out is through the following, there are two ways I tried with the similar results:

```
int* image_out = new int[128 * 128];
for (...) {
    /* assign image_out to zeros */
}
```

and the one using ITK interface:

```
out_image->SetRegions(region2d);
out_image->Allocate();
out_image->FillBuffer(0);
// Obtain the data buffer
int* image_out = out_image->GetOutputBuffer();
```

Then I setup CUDA as the following:

```
unsigned int size_in = 128 * 128 * 128;
unsigned int size_out = 128 * 128;
int *dev_in;
int *dev_out;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_in, size_in * sizeof(int) );
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_out, size_out * sizeof(int));
cudaMemcpy( dev_in, image_in, size_in * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
add_slices<<<size_in/64, 64 >>>(dev_in, dev_out);
cudaMemcpy( image_out, dev_out, size_out * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Is there any problem to the above code? The reason why I am seeking help here comes from the frastration that the above code sometimes might produce the right result (once every 50 times I run the code, maybe, I swear I have seen the correct result at least twice), while the rest of the time just produced some garbages. Does the issue comes from the atomicAdd() function? At the beginning my image type was of double, which CUDA doesn't support atomicAdd(double*, double) so I used the code provided by Nvidia as the following

```
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                                          (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;
    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, 
                        __double_as_longlong(val + 
                        __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    } while (assumed != old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

Then just for testing purpose I switched all my image to int then the situation was still the same that most of the time garbages while once in a blue moon correct result.

Do I need to turn on some compiling flag? I am using CMAKE to build the project using

```
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)
```

for the CUDA support. The following is the way I setup the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -arch=sm_30"),
```

maybe I missed something?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated and I will update the question if more info of the code is needed.

Comment: Are you initializing `image_out` somewhere before calling the kernel?

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the reply! Yes, I init'ed the image using the ITK library function image_out->Allocate() and image_out->FillBuffer(0); also I tried just simply passing a ordinary initialized C++ new() ed array and the result was the same.

Comment: Can you please edit in the simplest complete example into your question? You cannot pass a pointer allocated by C++ new to a CUDA kernel. If you are doing that, the problem has *nothing* to do with atomicAdd

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the suggestion. I have added a complete example to the question.

Comment: @talonmies Thanks talonmies you are a genius! Yeah.. I didn't really initialized the image_out. I need to memcpy to device for image_out too. Such dumb question. I missed it since I think image_out is the output.

Comment: Could you please add a short answer explaining what the problem was? This will get your question off the unanswered list (it's perfectly OK to answer your own question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the solution to this problem is adding the following line to initialize the memory pointed by dev_out.

```
cudaMemcpy( dev_out, image_out, size_out * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
```

I forgot to initialize it since I was thinking that it is a output variable and I initialized it on the host.

Just like that talonmies said, it has nothing to do with atomicAdd at all. Both int version and double version of atomicAdd works perfectly. Just remember to initialize your variable on device.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer, this helps everyone, including future visitors with a similar problem.